# Eror clearing File Explorer “Recent Files” History in Windows 11

Tags: window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lFK8.png)i did everything to try to fix it but I can't with normal methods that happened cause i changed my user folder name cause it had sign on it so some programs couldn't be installed with this name

U tried all visible solution from internet starting from clear history settings and privacy to clear cache and tempo files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations*
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations*
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent*
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe